# Angular2: Object key as a variable in a template

Tags: javascript, angular

In my template, I would like to pass an object parameter with a dynamic key.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | keys">
    <a [routerLink]="[url, {objectKey: item.key}]">
        {{ item.key }}{{ item.value }}
    </a>
</li>
```

In this example, the objectKey is a property of my object, but because it's javascript, it takes it as a string 'objectKey' ...

Comment: You could create a method where you pass the variables `objectKey` and `item.key` and get the constructed object returned.

Answer (score 3):

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | keys">
    <a [routerLink]="['/url', item.key]">   //<-- arguments should be array of
                                                   elements that form your url
        {{ item.key }}{{ item.value }}
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: you don't need to specify it as key-value object, just pass the argument as second parameter

Comment: @GuillaumeC make sure to mark Vamsi's answer as correct if it's correct. To me it looks like it is. Here are the docs on the [RouterLink directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use square brackets (if EcmaScript 6 is used):

```
{[objectKey]: item.key}
```

Comment: I tried to replace but it doesn't work :(
<li *ngFor="let item of items | keys">
    <a [routerLink]="url, {[objectKey]: item.key}]">
        {{ item.key }}{{ item.value }}
    </a>
</li>